Spring Modulith : how can Hero module get value team name from Team module?
I'm learning Spring Modulith.
There is 2 modules :

Hero module

HeroController with post hero (String heroName, String teamName) used to save a HeroEntity in database
HeroRepository that enable to get Hero entity
HeroEntity : String heroName, TeamEntity team


Team module

TeamRepository that enable to find a Team by name
TeamEntity
...




In post HeroController, how can I find Team (by using Team module) to save the Hero ? In other words, how can I use ApplicationEventPublisher in HeroController to find Team by team module and wait the response ?
Is it the right way that HeroEntity has a TeamEntity object that comes from the team module ?

Thanks for your help
